# Deduplicating content by removing similar rows of text in Python

Tags: python, nlp, duplicates, similarity, sentence-similarity

I'm fairly new to Python. While I know it's possible to deduplicate rows in Pandas with drop_duplicates for identical text results, **is there a way to drop *similar* rows of text**?

E.g. for this fictional collection of online article headlines, populated in chronological order

1 "The dog ate my homework" says confused child in Banbury

2 Confused Banbury child says dog ate homework

3 Why are dogs so cute

4 Teacher in disbelief as child says dog ate homework - Banbury Times

5 Dogs don't like eggs, here's why

6 The moment a senior stray is adopted - try not to cry

7 Dog smugglers in Banbury arrested in police sting operation

My ideal outcome would be that only rows 1, 3, 5, 6 and 7 remain, with rows 1, 2 and 4 having been grouped for similarity and then only 1, the oldest/ 'first' entry, kept.

(How) could I get there? Even advice purely about the grouping approach would be very helpful. I would want to be able to run this on hundreds of rows of text, *without having a specific, manually pre-determined article or headline to measure similarity against*, just group similar rows.

Thank you so much for your thoughts and time!

Comment: What have you tried? What issues do you have?

Comment: What if row A is similar to row B, B is similar to C, but A is not similar to C?

Comment: Did you mean sematic similarity of texts? Does your dataset contain two sentences with different words but the same similarity?

Comment: @I159 I started looking into FuzzyWuzzy but wasn't sure how to go about searching for similarity between lines of text that wasn't just comparing 2 lines. Wasn't being modest about being new to this. Any pointers on places to start looking for a solution would be great.

Comment: @Alex Hall exactly. In your experience is there a clustering approach that could work? I am open to exploring at this point.

Comment: @roddar92 thank you so much for your suggestion! Yes, semantic similarity.

Answer (score 0):

You cam try to obtain your data with `doc2vec` ([example of usage](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html)), then cluster your text with cosine distance with `kmedoids` of hierarchical algorithms.